# React not keeping state

Tags: reactjs, list, state

I'd like to implement a list with a button to add an item and a button, on each item, to remove it.

Here a basic sample of my code, which is much more complex on my project but with the same logic.

**App.tsx**

```
import React, { createRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import ListItem from "./list_item";

const testData = [
    {
        value: 1,
    }
]
type EnhancedListItem = {
    id: number;
    ref: React.RefObject<any>;
    item: React.ReactElement;
}

function App() {

    const [enhancedListItems, setEnhancedListItems] = useState<EnhancedListItem[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const newEnhancedListItems: EnhancedListItem[] = [];
        testData.forEach((t, i) => {
            const ref = createRef<any>();
            const item = React.cloneElement(<ListItem />, { id: i, defaultValue: t.value, ref });
            newEnhancedListItems.push({ id: i, ref, item });
        });
        setEnhancedListItems(newEnhancedListItems);
    }, []);

    function onAddListItemButtonClick(): void {
        const ref = createRef<any>();
        const newId = enhancedListItems.reduce((p: number, c) => Math.max(p, c.id), 0) + 1;
        const newObject = { defaultValue: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10), id: newId }
        const item = React.cloneElement(<ListItem />, { ...newObject, ref });
        setEnhancedListItems([...enhancedListItems, { id: newId, item, ref }]);
    }

    function onRemoveButtonClick(id: number): void {
        setEnhancedListItems(enhancedListItems.filter(t => t.id !== id));
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {enhancedListItems.map((t, i) => (
                <div key={i}>
                    <span>{t.item}</span>
                    <span><button onClick={() => onRemoveButtonClick(t.id)}>-</button></span>
                </div>
            ))}
            <button onClick={onAddListItemButtonClick}>+</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**ListItem.tsx**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export type ListItemProps = {
    id?: number;
    defaultValue?: string;
}

function ListItem(props: ListItemProps, ref: React.ForwardedRef<any>): React.ReactElement {

    const [value, setValue] = useState(props.defaultValue ?? "");

    function onInputChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void {
        setValue(e.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <span>{props.id}</span>
            <input type="text" value={value} onChange={onInputChange} />
        </div>
    );
}

export default React.forwardRef(ListItem);
```

My problem is: When I click the remove button on an item, the item itself is removed (its ID disappears), but the value of the other items changes. It seems that the last item has been removed, every time. That means that all the items take the value of the preceding item in the list.
Do you have any idea why the state of the input value is not kept? Is there a problem with the clone element process?

Thanks a lot for your help!

**Update**

This simple code does not work either. Same problem...

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

type EnhancedListItem = {
    id: number;
}

function App() {

    const [enhancedListItems, setEnhancedListItems] = useState<EnhancedListItem[]>([]);

    function onAddListItemButtonClick(): void {
        const newId = enhancedListItems.reduce((p: number, c) => Math.max(p, c.id), 0) + 1;
        setEnhancedListItems([...enhancedListItems, { id: newId }]);
    }

    function onRemoveButtonClick(id: number): void {
        setEnhancedListItems(enhancedListItems.filter(t => t.id !== id));
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {enhancedListItems.map((t, i) => (
                <div key={i}>
                    <span>{t.id}</span>
                    <input type="text" />
                    <button onClick={() => onRemoveButtonClick(t.id)}>-</button>
                </div>
            ))}
            <button onClick={onAddListItemButtonClick}>+</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Oh, wow. This is some of the most complicated and convoluted code to achieve something very simple I've seen in a long time. Take a step back and try to understand the basics. Refs are not something you normally need to use. Basically the only use-case for it is to interact directly with the dom (things like focus an element etc.). For this example you don't need a single one. You don't need to create/clone elements.  Most of the code here is just complicated for no reason.

Comment: You're right. Actually, I'm also using the ref to focus the input in the project. But yes, I admit it's complicated. I was thinking about not using the refs and passing function via the components props, but anyway, I'd also like to know why this code is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few not-best-practices that could explain what you're seeing.

**First**, as @super commented, your code is complex. I'd render the `ListItem` (or display + input) components directly (closer to your second example) rather than trying to create them in a loop and clone them. You may also be able to use `autoFocus` (or pass a ref to the first element only) to avoid tracking an array of refs. You [don't need an effect](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect) to set the initial value; instead, pass a function to calculate the initial value directly.

```
const [enhancedListItems, setEnhancedListItems] = useState(() => testData.map(t => /*...*/));
```

None of this likely explains your bug, but it will make the code simpler to maintain.

**Second**, your `onAddListItemButtonClick` and `onRemoveButtonClick` functions refer to the *current* `enhancedListItems`, which means that you can have a stale closure referring to an out-of-date list items. I don't think this is happening in your case (I think your code re-renders promptly whenever the closure needs to change), but it's easy to fix by passing a function that takes the current state, instead of directly referring to the current state.

```
const onRemoveButtonClick = (id: number) => {
  setEnhancedListItems(
    prevEnhancedListItems => prevEnhancedListItems.filter(t => t.id !== id)
  );
}
```

**Third** (and possibly the cause of your bug), the purpose of a `key` in React is to *uniquely* identify each element in a list. Your code uses the list items' position in the array as their key. That's a common and convenient way to silence React's warning about needing a key. But, for example, if you render three items (keys `0`, `1`, and `2`), and then the user deletes the second item, the code then renders keys `0` and `1` - you're telling React that it was actually the third item that was deleted. Try using the unique `t.id` as the key instead.

Comment: Tanks for all! I finally solved my problem by only manipulating the data instead of react elements, and then separate the data from the render. But I now have a better understanding of React. I learnt a lot.